# “could not resolve host” error in libcurl using c++

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

The code snippet is as follows:

```
const int BUFFERSIZE = 50*1024;
char lLoadedData[BUFFERSIZE];
memset(lLoadedData, 0, sizeof(lLoadedData));

mstrURL = "http://www.google.com";
CURL* lCurlHandle = curl_easy_init();
if (lCurlHandle)
{
    //url
    if ((error_code = curl_easy_setopt(lCurlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, mstrURL)) != CURLE_OK)
        return;

    if((error_code = curl_easy_setopt(lCurlHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)lLoadedData)) != CURLE_OK)
        return;

    error_code = curl_easy_perform(lCurlHandle);

    if (error_code == CURLE_OK)
    {           
              ...
        }
}
```

The error_code after executing curl_easy_perform() is CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_HOST.

I have changed the DNS server to 8.8.8.8 and 4.4.4.4, but the error_code is still unchanged.

Does anybody know how to fix this problem? Thanks!

Environment: Windows server 2008, VS 2010.

================update=====================
Seems the parameter is wrong. should be:
if ((error_code = curl_easy_setopt(lCurlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, mstrURL.**c_str()**)) != CURLE_OK)

Comment: My condolences for having to develop on a consumer OS.  I can't answer your question, but i can tell you that 4.4.4.4 is unlikely to be a nameserver.  You probably meant 8.8.4.4 instead.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. but it also fails on 8.8.4.4

Comment: yep, hence my ``I can't answer your question''.  You might want to use a platform which allows you to analyze the issue in a structured fashion.  On unix, i'd ktrace it to find out what goes wrong exactly, then use a debugger to step through the general location of the error. On Windows, I'd ask Clippy, then call customer support.

Answer (score 3):

I was having similar error. When I checked the log message by enabling the verbose option, curl tries to rebuild the url whenever I passed it as string. And the rebuild url process produced an invalid url.
It only worked when I put the url directly on the curl_easy_setopt method such as: curl_easy_setopt(lCurlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com"). The curl would not work if I put the url in a variable and pass it on parameter. 
But then, I checked the manuals of CURLOPT_URL in [here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_URL.html). The url parameter should be char pointer. Therefore, I converted my string url into a char pointer.

So my suggestion is converting your (probably) string mstrURL into char pointer and lets see if it works. If you use std::string, you can use c_str() to convert it to char pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you're using a proxy that you forgot to tell libcurl about.

You can switch on **CURLOPT_VERBOSE** to get more info from libcurl about what it does and what happens.